# How do I limit what versions of Visual Studio are allowed to connect to TFS / TFVC?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfvc

We have seen issues in the past when developers use an old version of Visual Studio for checking files in and out of TFVC.  ("Old" in this case being several releases older than the TFS on the server.)

We would like to configure something on our TFS server that would prohibit connections by old versions of Visual Studio.  Is this possible?

Comment: It occurs to me that this may be an X-Y problem. What **problem** is being caused by developers using older versions of Visual Studio to interact with TFVC?

Comment: Our server has TFS 2015 and most of the developers are using VS 2013 or VS 2015.  One developer prefers the Pending Changes window in VS 2010.  There have been several instances of VS 2010 checking out files without getting the latest.  When the files are checked in, changes are lost.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no way to accomplish that, and it shouldn't really matter in any case. Visual Studio and TFVC work fine together regardless of the version of either (with the exception of maybe VS 2008, where you have to use the MSSCCI provider to work with modern versions of TFS/TFVC).